# How to call function of number picker

Tags: android, object, picker

I think the following is a basic problem.

I using this number Picker as there is none provided by Android SDK:
http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5&cpage=1#comment-10645

I have integrated it in an inflated alertdialog. Here the inflated layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <com.example.NumberPicker
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have added a button to the alertdialog. If it is clicked, I want to get the current value of the number picker.

The number picker class provides a function:

```
 public static int getCurrent() {
        return mCurrent;
    }
```

Problem is that I am not aware how to call it. I have no object of the class.
If I call it via com.example.NumberPicker.getCurrent(), I have to declare it static and this has some negative side-effects.

Does someone know how I get the object of the picker class in order to call the getCurrent() function?

I think simple to create a new object is not the right way, because I want to call the function from the running object in my alerdialog.

Edit:
As I have expected:

```
NumberPicker np = new NumberPicker(MainScreen.this);
Log.v("TEST", "" + np.getCurrent());
```

This gives me always 0

Edit 2:
I added an Android ID:

```
<com.example.NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I my code I do following:

```
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(
                    R.layout.backfall_layout, null);



            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreen.this)
                    .setTitle(this.getString(R.string.relapse))
                    .setView(textEntryView)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                                NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);

                                Log.v("TEST", "" + np.getCurrent());

--
```

But now my App crashes after pressing the button..

Edit 3:

Solved it: I have to call

```
NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.cigarettesPicker);
            np.setCurrent(1);
```

Comment: Instead of using built-in NumberPicker, why don't you take a look at this UI library: http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does someone know how I get the object of the picker class in order to call the getCurrent() function?

1. Add an `android:id` value to your `NumberPicker` element in your layout XML.
2. When you inflate the layout for your `AlertDialog`, call `findViewById()` on the inflated layout, passing in the ID you supplied in step #1, and casting the result to be a `NumberPicker`.

Comment: Thx. I think this is the right way. But my app crashes now. I add my new code to the post above.